# Is this sentence considered a double negative "Neither scenario does not involve fractions."?

Tags: negation

Is this sentence considered a double negative "Neither scenario does not involve fractions." ?

Comment: Where did you encounter this? I have never seen neither modifying a singular noun  like that. (I am a learner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a double negative.

In the given sentence you use *neither* to refer to each of two scenarios, making a negative statement that includes both of them. This is what the sentence should look like:

> Neither scenario involves fractions.